# Rounding value of BigDecimal

Tags: java

I want to create a method that take two parameters. The first one is the amount (`String`) and the second is the Rounding type based on rounding type. It should round a value up or round down or so on...

```
public static String roundingAmount(String amount, String mode) {
    if (amount != null) {
        double dAmt = Double.parseDouble(amount);
        if (mode.equalsIgnoreCase("Rounded"))
            BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(dAmt).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        else if (mode.equalsIgnoreCase("Round UP"))
            BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(dAmt).setScale(0, RoundingMode.CEILING);
        else if (mode.equalsIgnoreCase("Round Down"))
            BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(dAmt).setScale(0, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
        else if (mode.equalsIgnoreCase("NA")) {
            return amount;
        }
        String newNumber = String.format("%.2f", decimal.doubleValue());
        return newNumber;
    }
    return amount;
}
```

It shows error decimal not found.
Can you help me?

Comment: In which line you got an error?

Comment: line number 14.

Comment: try to declare and initialize decimal when function brackets start like
BigDecimal decimal=0;

Answer (score 0):

`decimal` is only defined inside each of the `if` branches, so it's out of scope outside them. You could declare it outside of those blocks, which may also save you some code duplication:

```
public static String roundingAmount(String amount,String mode){
     if(amount != null){
         double dAmt = Double.parseDouble(amount);
         BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(dAmt); // Here!

        if (mode.equalsIgnoreCase("Rounded"))
            decimal = decimal.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        else if (mode.equalsIgnoreCase("Round UP"))
            decimal = decimal.setScale(0, RoundingMode.CEILING);
        else if(mode.equalsIgnoreCase("Round Down"))
            decimal = decimal.setScale(0, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
        else if(mode.equalsIgnoreCase("NA")) {
            return amount;
        }
        String newNumber = String.format("%.2f" , decimal.doubleValue());
        return newNumber;
    }
    return amount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding Alok's answer with the DRY principle (Don't Repeat Yourself):

```
public static String roundingAmount(String amount,String mode){
    RoundingMode roundingMode;
    if(amount!=null){
        if(mode.equalsIgnoreCase("Rounded"))
            roundingMode = RoundingMode.HALF_UP;
        else if(mode.equalsIgnoreCase("Round UP"))
            roundingMode = RoundingMode.CEILING;
        else if(mode.equalsIgnoreCase("Round Down"))
            roundingMode = RoundingMode.FLOOR;
        else if(mode.equalsIgnoreCase("NA"))
            return amount;
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(mode + " is not an accepted mode");

        double dAmt=Double.parseDouble(amount);
        BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(dAmt).setScale(0, roudingMode);
        String newNumber = String.format("%.2f" , decimal.doubleValue());
        return newNumber;
    }
    return amount;
}
```

In order to improve this even more I would suggest passing the `RoundingMode` enum directly to the method instead of having to type it in the code itself. That would also enable using a switch statement instead of multipe String comparisons